# Obj-C IBAction (id)sender

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, variables, ibaction

I have an `IBAction` like:

```
- (IBAction)thisThing:(id)sender {

  [self doSomething];
}
```

I would like do this (manually call the IBAction):

```
[self thisThing];
```

However I obviously need to do `[self thisThing:...];`. <- (what the heck goes after the colon?)

I'm not sure what `(id)sender` is supposed to be. How do call it manually without needing to click the button that it's tied to? [I searched for anything about `IBAction (id)sender`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=title%3AIBAction+%28id%29sender) and the results came up completely empty.

Comment: Just do `[self thisThing:nil];` or just get rid of it completely since you aren't using it so change the declared method to `- (IBAction)thisThing;`

Comment: Well, there's more than just `[self doSomething];` in there, i just used it as an example. Is `nil` the standard way to call an IBAction without using the button, etc.? thanks

Comment: Really I guess the question is - "What is (id)sender?"

Comment: Also, I just signed up here today - so might be a bit unfamiliar. But I noticed a negative score for my question. I don't think it's that bad, although maybe the person who thought so is. https://medium.com/the-physics-arxiv-blog/aad9d49da238

Comment: IF there is more in there please can you share. What we give you could break the rest of your code. It's always best to share all the code not just a cut down version or a version nothing like your code. We can't give an accurate answer otherwise.

Comment: I have provided a -1 for two reasons. 1) That link is completely broken that you have provided in your question. 2) You have indicated that this isn't your actual code you are using and parts are missing. This isn't the way this site works you need to provide all relevant code as you have it not a cut down version that doesn't look anything like your code. I will remove my -1 if I feel satisfied you are sharing the relevant information and you fixthat link.

Answer (score 1):

> what the heck goes after the colon?

Well it depends on how you have written code inside the `IBAction`. Say for a calculator app, if all buttons are hooked up with the same `IBAction` then you would need sender (in this case `NSButton`) to identify which button got touched/clicked.

```
-(IBAction) buttonClicked:(id) sender {
    // sender's identifier or Tag will let us know the number clicked here
    [self doSomeThing];
}
```

But if you had `IBActions` for each and every button you would not need to be dependent on sender.

```
-(IBAction) firstButtonClicked:(id)sender;
-(IBAction) secondButtonClicked:(id)sender;
```

and so on ...

So in the first case if I want to programatically invoke the action I would pass the sender with appropriate attributes set to make sure the correct button got clicked. In second case just pass `nil` as it does not depend upon sender's value.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the IBOutlet of the button, you can pass that like `[self thisThing:btn];`

Or simply pass nil, `[self thisThing:nil];` (if you are not using sender inside the IBAction)

Answer (score 0):

While popeye's comment answers your question, here's another perspective.

You have complete control over the action method. If you aren't using the `sender` parameter for anything in that method, then you do not have to supply it when calling it manually. By not supply it I mean pass `nil` as the value of the parameter.

Normally, it will contain a pointer to the control that is wired up to the action. If you did want to use if for something, they you would simply cast `sender` to the type of the control and do whatever with it.

Comment: "then you do not have to supply it when calling it manually", but something has to go in it's place such as `nil` correct?

Comment: @lisa Yes, for syntactic purposes, something has to go in there. `nil` is pretty much the same as nothing.

Comment: Well, three bytes short of nothing. :)

Comment: @LisaStevens haha, actually, just one - `nil` is effectively the same as `0`.

Answer (score 0):

`- (IBAction)thisThing:(id)sender`

In here,

`-` denotes the start of a instance method, whereas `+` means class(static) method.

`( .. )` indicate return type. IBAction is actually `void`. Using `IBAction` instead of `void` tells that this method will be associated with UI(.nib) events.

`thisThing` is the name of the method, followed by parameter list.

In C view point, actual function names is something like `thisThing:`. That is, number of parameter modifies function name (external linkage).

If you meant to call `thisThing:` but write `[self thisThing]`, you are calling different (not existing) method.

So, you must write `:`. What actual value to pass? One can decide this by looking at the method implementation.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (IBAction)thisThing:(id)sender {
}
```

Is an **event handler**. That means that it is called when an event is sent by someone. A typical example of an event is a click on a button, it that case, the button sends the event (that means the button, a `NSButton` instance, is the sender).

Having the sender as a parameter is useful when you use the same event handler for events coming from different sources, e.g.

```
- (IBAction)buttonTapped:(id)sender {
    if (sender == self.myButton1) {
       //button 1 was tapped
    }
    else if (sender == self.myButton2) {
       //button 2 was tapped
    }
}
```

If this case, if you want to call the event handler manually, you just call

```
[self buttonTapped:self.myButton1];
```

If you don't use the `sender` parameter, then you can simply call

```
[self buttonTapped:nil];
```

However, the parameter is completely optional, so you can eliminate it:

```
- (IBAction)buttonTapped {
    // ...
}

[self buttonTapped];
```

On a separate note, it's never good to call event handlers manually. Event handlers serve to handle events. If you need to perform the same action manually, separate it from the event handler, e.g.

```
- (IBAction)buttonTapped {
    [self doSomething];
}
```

instead of calling `[self buttonTapped]`, call `[self doSomething]`